# How to create SQL Server table schema from a XML schema? (with .NET and Visual Studio 2008)

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, xml, sql-server-2005

I have a XML schema, and I know that "xsd.exe" can generate the C# code for it. But I want to know if is possible to automatically create the MS SQL Server 2005+ tables from the XSD, with the help of this or other tools.

BTW <strike>I didn't get what the C# code generated by "xsd.exe" is worth for.</strike>
What's the difference between code generated by CodeXS and xsd.exe?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the XSD2DB utility

This is the Example 
xsd2db.exe -f true -l [Server Name] -n [Database Name] -s D:\po.xsd -t sql

Link for Help
http://xsd2db.sourceforge.net/

Answer (score 2):

Disclaimer: I haven't done this myself, but I bookmarked these links a little while ago when I was thinking about doing this.  This guy's T-SQL is usually brilliant, so I'd recommend it highly:

http://weblogs.sqlteam.com/peterl/archive/2009/03/05/Extract-XML-structure-automatically.aspx

http://weblogs.sqlteam.com/peterl/archive/2009/06/04/Extract-XML-structure-automatically-part-2.aspx

Answer (score 2):

> BTW I didn't get what the C# code
>   generated by "xsd.exe" is worth for.

I am assuming what you mean is "I don't understand how the generated code is useful"

The purpose of the code it generates is to serialize using the Microsoft serialization subsystem in .NET.  If you create a new XmlSerializer(typeof(GeneratedType)), you can then call Serialize() and Deserialze() on it to go to/from Xml and objects.

In a more complicated code generator, such as CodeXS, it becomes even easier, as they generate helpers for you:  GeneratedType.FromXML(Stream/String) to deserialize and myGeneratedType.Xml to serialize.

These generated classes allow you to work off a published schema, and have total confidence that any XML generated that meets the schema will parse and be generated using these types.  You don't need to do any work to get the data out of the XML (ie no XML DOM access) and you don't need to think twice about generating XML that is compliant with your schema.  It just works :)

Comment: Thanks, I used CodeXS generated code, and it seems to me much simpler and easier to use than "xsd.exe" generated code.

Comment: Is there a good tutorial or place that I can download CodeXS? Is it still maintained?

Answer (score 0):

As long as you can successfully parse your XML schema, you should be able to create the appropriate database scripts and execute them which will create your tables.

Comment: But how? Writing the script manually? There isn't an automatic way to do that?

Comment: Jader Dias: I don't know, but look at it this way...whatever automatic way there is would have had to have been written by someone at some point in time. If there isn't an automatic solution already out there, write your own?

Comment: @TXI: There doesn't have to be an automatic way to map, because there doesn't have to be a mapping. XML is not relational.

Comment: @John: I can imagine a way to map a XML to multiple related tables

Comment: @Jader: does this have to work for all valid XML schemas? If so, then you're out of luck. XML can represent some things that cannot be represented in a relational database. If you limit yourself to those schemas that can map to relational, then it's not that hard. In fact, consider the schemas created by the DataSet Designer in VS2008. It will cheerfully ignore certain changes you make by hand, then rewrite them to match the nearest relational equivalent. If you had actually meant what you wrote, you'd be out of luck.

Answer (score 0):

I know that this is an old topic, however it was really helpful to me to know how it can be done. Maybe it would be helpful to others.

[More advanced examples can be seen at Microsoft page.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/sqlxml-annotated-xsd-schemas-xpath-queries/sqlxml-4-0-net-framework-support-using-bulk-load?view=sql-server-ver15)

So, it is possible to create manually SQL table from XSD. For example, we have the following xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<foo>
   <row>
      <CAR_NUM>624</CAR_NUM>
      <CAR_ORDER>1</CAR_ORDER>      
   </row>
   <row>
      <CAR_NUM>623</CAR_NUM>
      <CAR_ORDER>2</CAR_ORDER>      
   </row>
   <row>
      <CAR_NUM>681</CAR_NUM>
      <CAR_ORDER>3</CAR_ORDER>      
   </row>
   <row>
      <CAR_NUM>625</CAR_NUM>
      <CAR_ORDER>4</CAR_ORDER>      
   </row>
   <row>
      <CAR_NUM>680</CAR_NUM>
      <CAR_ORDER>5</CAR_ORDER>      
   </row>
</foo>
```

So out XSD will look like this:

```
<xsd:schema xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"  
            xmlns:sql="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:mapping-schema">  
    <xsd:element name="row" sql:relation="CAR"   
                            sql:key-fields="CAR_NUM">  
        <xsd:complexType> 
            <xsd:sequence>
                <xsd:element name="CAR_NUM"   type="xsd:integer" />   
                <xsd:element name="CAR_ORDER"   type="xsd:integer" />  
            </xsd:sequence>
        </xsd:complexType>
    </xsd:element>

</xsd:schema>
```

And SQL table will look like this:

```
CREATE TABLE CAR (  
    CAR_NUM   INT ,  
    CAR_ORDER INT 
GO
```

And then you can use `Interop.SQLXMLBULKLOADLib` library to load data into SQLServer:

```
try
{       
    var xmlFileName = @".your address here..\GetInformReplyEdited.xml";
    var xsdScheme = @".your address here..\scheme.xsd";

    var connString = "Provider=sqloledb;server=yourServer;database=Test;integrated security=SSPI";
    SQLXMLBULKLOADLib.SQLXMLBulkLoad4Class objBL = new SQLXMLBULKLOADLib.SQLXMLBulkLoad4Class
    {
        ConnectionString = connString,
        ErrorLogFile = "error.xml",
        KeepIdentity = false
    };
    objBL.Execute(xsdScheme, xmlFileName);
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
}
```